# Assume a role to an external account to access a specific instance of my account as Session Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-ssm

I am a beginner studying AWS.

I'd like to give a role external account B so that It can access my account A.

I want to use Session Manager(System Manager) to record commands for external accounts.

- My Account ID : A
- External Account ID : B

So, In my Account A, I made ssm-accoutB-role.

connected policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:StartSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:REGION:ACCOUNT-ID_A:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ssm:resourceTag/ssm": [
                        "true"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:TerminateSession",
                "ssm:ResumeSession"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:session/${aws:username}-*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and set the trust relationship with AccountB

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID_B:user/IAM-USER"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

and I attached Role for `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore` policy with Instance.

Using AWS-CLI, I send commands `aws sts get-caller-identity`, and export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and so on...
success to assume Role.

and `aws ssm start-session \ --target instance-id`

// This instance in private subnet connected NAT Gateway

It appears error "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the TerminateSession operation: User~~"

How to set the IAM ROLE for ssm...

Please help me!

Comment: Seemingly policies are valid. Is external ID Federated ID? Example3 in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-restrict-access-examples.html#restrict-access-example-user-sessions) has some methods which might work.

Comment: Can you add edit your question and attach the policy which you attach to the user in Account B - "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID_B:user/IAM-USER"? In addition it would be nice if you show or describe how exactly you are assuming the role in Account A.